# html css make full list clickable

Tags: html, html-lists

I have html

```css
li.count-instagram {
    background-color: #674538 !important;
    padding: 5px 0 !important;
    display:block !important;
}
```

```html
<li class="count-instagram"><a class="icon" href="#" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">LINK</a><span class="items"><span class="count" style="color: #ffffff !important;">2665</span><span class="label" style="color: #ffffff !important;">followers</span></span></li>
```

I need this list clickable in full wide, please help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```css
li.count-instagram {
  background-color: #674538 !important;
}
.count-instagram a{
  display:block !important;
  padding: 5px 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<li class="count-instagram"><a class="icon" href="#" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">LINK<span class="items"><span class="count" style="color: #ffffff !important;">2665</span><span class="label" style="color: #ffffff !important;">followers</span></span></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the code specified below and your issue will be sorted.

```
<li class="count-instagram">
<a class="icon" href="#" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">
    <div class="items">
        <span class="count" style="color: #ffffff !important;">2665</span>
        <span class="label" style="color: #ffffff !important;">followers</span>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: I no capable to edit html. just can only touch css, sorry this is wordpress plugin. if I edit the plugin when update come, my tweak will gone. sorry I should be notice this in tread